# Chrome Unresponsive After Form Submit Postsback in New Tab - Ruby Watir-Webdriver

Tags: javascript, ruby, google-chrome, selenium, watir-webdriver

I am updating a script that uploads a file, then extracts data from the response before continuing the upload loop.

I believe the problem is when the file is uploaded and I am running the javascript that submits the form(or .click submit), the Postback returns in a new tab. I believe watir is hanging and becoming unresponsive while waiting for the postback from the page that submitted, but it has already been opened in a new tab(old version of this script used classic watir's click_no_wait often). The script timesout and I lose attachment to the window, even if I Rescue the timeout am unable to interact with the browser at all.

Have been trying to solve this issue for days now. Running a simple Ruby line

```
  p "Submitting..."
  @b.execute_script("javascript:UpldFil();")
```

Here is debug from this submit after already on the response page:

```
"Submitting..."
-> POST session/11324ae12918982202d689070e60ee2c/execute
>>> {"script":"javascript:UpldFil();","args":[]}
> {"Content-Length"=>"44", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Accept"=>"application/json"}
Exception `#<Class:0x5f11b18>' at C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:64 - execution expired
Exception `Timeout::Error' at C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:79 - execution expired
```

The Function UpldFil()

```
function UpldFil() {
var windowName = "Submission"; 
var fm = document.forms[0];

if (fm.FilNam.value == "") {
alert("Please select a file for submission");
return false;
 }
}   
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Using: 
Ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i386-mingw32],
Watir-Webdriver-0.6.1,
Chrome 19

I can not currently update any of these as they are too many dependents that would need to be updated as well. Plans for updates and this problem is in phase 1 of the upgrades.

Ran this locally in an up-to-date environment of ruby/chrome/webdriver. Here is the debug:

```
"Submitting..."
-> POST session/257d1718ab961a6e92604cfb845ee6ed/execute
>>> http://127.0.0.1:9515/session/257d1718ab961a6e92604cfb845ee6ed/execute |
{"script":"javascript:UpldFil();","args":[]}
> {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length"=>"44"}
Exception `IO::EWOULDBLOCKWaitReadable' at C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153 - A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. - read would block
<- {"sessionId":"257d1718ab961a6e92604cfb845ee6ed","status":0,"value":null}
-> DELETE session/257d1718ab961a6e92604cfb845ee6ed
Exception `IO::EWOULDBLOCKWaitReadable' at C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153 - A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. - read would block
<- {"sessionId":"257d1718ab961a6e92604cfb845ee6ed","status":0,"value":null}
#<ChildProcess::Windows::Process:0x4961178 @args=["C:\\tools/chromedriver.exe",
"--port=9515"], @started=true, @exit_code=nil, @io=nil, @cwd=nil, @detach=false, @duplex=false, @leader=false, @environment={}, @pid=5040, @handle=#<ChildProcess::Windows::Handle:0x4960e00 @pid=5040, @pointer=#<FFI::Pointer address=0x0002d8>, @closed=false>> : [{:exited?=>false, :code=>259}]
Exception `IO::EWOULDBLOCKWaitReadable' at C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153 - A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. - read would block
#<ChildProcess::Windows::Process:0x4961178 @args=["C:\\tools/chromedriver.exe", "--port=9515"], @started=true, @exit_code=nil, @io=nil, @cwd=nil, @detach=false, @duplex=false, @leader=false, @environment={}, @pid=5040, @handle=#<ChildProcess::Windows::Handle:0x4960e00 @pid=5040, @pointer=#<FFI::Pointer address=0x0002d8>, @closed=false>> : ["polling 5 seconds for exit"]
```

Debug continues on to spit out 20-30 of the ChildProcess lines, browser crashes and closes out.

Comment: Can you "attach" to the new tab using [`.use`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Window#use-instance_method)?

Comment: No, I lose all connection to the browser window. .use was one of the first options I tried, also tried using a window.last, and attempting to send_keys that would flip tab to previous. I can't even read text on the page once I hit submit. All of these browser requests result in more timeouts
Passing in return false before executing the javascript seems to let me retain control, but I lose confirmation information that the file was uploaded

Comment: Are you able to at least test if this problem occurs with up-to-date versions of everything? It would at least help narrow the problem down - ie is this a known issue that is already fixed or a problem that is still outstanding.

Comment: @JustinKo Have most of a modern environment set up locally that I should be able to test in today after doing a few tweaks, will report back

Comment: @JustinKo Updated my Q with debug information from running locally on up-to-date environment

Comment: Great. I guess the question now is can you create a page that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I have the know how to mock the site and host.. Especially because we are logged into an account and it looks like session variables are being passed with the Posts. I would give the site but it would be useless without any way to log in